# Single AND condition gives the same output as WHERE condition

Tags: sql, where-clause, and-operator

I tried to compose a query on **data.stackexchange.com** which would give me the answer to the question what the percentage of users who have written posts which were viewed over 1000 times and who possess badges of a certain class.

**Problem**: if I write `AND ViewCount > 1000` I get the same result as `WHERE ViewCount > 1000`
I don't understand why it happens

The query with WHERE:

```
SELECT 
TOP 1000 
Class, (Count(Badges.UserId)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) From Badges)) AS Percentage 
FROM Badges 
WHERE Badges.UserId IN (SELECT Posts.OwnerUserId FROM Posts 
INNER JOIN 
Badges ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Badges.UserId 
WHERE ViewCount > 1000) 
GROUP BY Class 
ORDER BY Class
```

The query with AND:

```
SELECT 
TOP 1000 
Class, (Count(Badges.UserId)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) From Badges)) AS Percentage 
FROM Badges 
WHERE Badges.UserId IN (SELECT Posts.OwnerUserId FROM Posts 
INNER JOIN 
Badges ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Badges.UserId 
AND ViewCount > 1000) 
GROUP BY Class 
ORDER BY Class
```

Output (for some reason it is the same in both cases):

1 class - 2 percent

2 class - 15 percent

3 class - 45 percent

Comment: Could you add table definitions to your question?

Comment: I think, it's an obvious because you are using INNER JOIN, so it will return same result both in AND,WHERE condition but it can behave differently in LEFT JOIN and return different result set.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what kind of logical collision you see here?

Comment: @IvanStarostin As long as I understand, I'm not supposed to use AND operator on its own without WHERE. So, it should be `WHERE condition 1 AND condition 2`. I do not get why I was allowed to use AND condition without WHERE and got the same result as if I used WHERE condition instead.

Comment: @Anya In your opinion what should be the answer in both cases ?

Comment: So yo don't see any logical collisions here, but surprised by syntax. Correct? RTFM would eliminate the problem.

Comment: chill out, I'm only a beginner.

Comment: It's fine bro, you can check my answer below to understand the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `AND` to connect the two expressions in the `ON` condition of the `JOIN`. Focus on the inner query:

```
SELECT Posts.OwnerUserId FROM Posts 
INNER JOIN Badges ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Badges.UserId 
WHERE ViewCount > 1000
```

Versus:

```
SELECT Posts.OwnerUserId FROM Posts 
INNER JOIN Badges
ON (
    Posts.OwnerUserId = Badges.UserId 
    AND ViewCount > 1000
)
```

These two queries are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out with this, if you are confusing for the same case as below:
**In SQL SERVER**

```
CREATE TABLE #a(catId INT, catName VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #b(productId INT, catId INT)

INSERT INTO #a VALUES 
(1, 'Test1'),
(2, 'Test2'),
(3, 'Test3'),
(4, 'Test4')

INSERT INTO #b VALUES 
(5, 1),
(6, 2),
(7, 3),
(8, 1)

--Return data what exists in both tables
SELECT a.*, b.productId
FROM #a a
INNER JOIN #b b ON b.catId = a.catId
AND b.catId < 3

--Same as above
SELECT a.*, b.productId
FROM #a a
INNER JOIN #b b ON b.catId = a.catId
WHERE b.catId < 3

--Same as above
SELECT a.*, b.productId
FROM #a a
LEFT JOIN #b b ON b.catId = a.catId
WHERE b.catId < 3

--Return all exists in first table though not exist in second table
SELECT a.*, b.productId
FROM #a a
LEFT JOIN #b b ON b.catId = a.catId
AND b.catId < 3
```